# How to setup AWS SNS Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

Trying to create Endpoints using ARN and device token.
For generating the endpoints I have used the below class in Android Application.
I am not receiving notification from AWS SNS, is there anything that I'm missing to add in the code?

To generate device token I have added this line.

```kotlin
var token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token


    class EndpointRegistration {

    companion object {

        var client = AmazonSNSClient() //provide credentials here
        val awsCredentials: AWSCredentials = BasicAWSCredentials(BuildConfig.AWS_ACCESS, BuildConfig.AWS_SECRET_KEY)

        var arnStorage: String? = null
    
        fun registerWithSNS(userToken: String, context: Context) {

            var endpointArn: String? = retrieveEndpointArn()
            val token = userToken
            var updateNeeded = false
            var createNeeded = null == endpointArn
            if (createNeeded) {
                // No platform endpoint ARN is stored; need to call createEndpoint.
                endpointArn = createEndpoint(context, token)
                createNeeded = false
            }
            println("Retrieving platform endpoint data...")
            // Look up the platform endpoint and make sure the data in it is current, even if
            // it was just created.
            try {
                val geaReq = GetEndpointAttributesRequest()
                        .withEndpointArn(endpointArn)
                val geaRes: GetEndpointAttributesResult = client.getEndpointAttributes(geaReq)
                updateNeeded = (geaRes.attributes["Token"] != token
                        || !geaRes.attributes["Enabled"].equals("true", ignoreCase = true))
            } catch (nfe: NotFoundException) {
                // We had a stored ARN, but the platform endpoint associated with it
                // disappeared. Recreate it.
                createNeeded = true
            }
            if (createNeeded) {
                createEndpoint(context, token)
            }
            println("updateNeeded = $updateNeeded")
            if (updateNeeded) {
                // The platform endpoint is out of sync with the current data;
                // update the token and enable it.
                println("Updating platform endpoint $endpointArn")
                val attribs: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                attribs["Token"] = token
                attribs["Enabled"] = "true"
                val saeReq = SetEndpointAttributesRequest()
                        .withEndpointArn(endpointArn)
                        .withAttributes(attribs)
                client.setEndpointAttributes(saeReq)
                Log.d("Updatingd", "=" + client.endpointPrefix)
            }
        }

        private fun createEndpoint(context: Context, token: String): String? {
            var endpointArn: String? = null
            endpointArn = try {
                println("Creating platform endpoint with token $token")
                client = AmazonSNSClient(awsCredentials)
                client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

                val cpeReq = CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
                        .withPlatformApplicationArn(BuildConfig.PLATFORM_ARN)
                        .withToken(token)
                val cpeRes: CreatePlatformEndpointResult = client
                        .createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq)
                cpeRes.endpointArn
            } catch (ipe: InvalidParameterException) {
                val message: String = ipe.getErrorMessage()
                println("Exception message: $message")
                val p: Pattern = Pattern
                        .compile(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists " +
                                "with the same [Tt]oken.*")
                val m: Matcher = p.matcher(message)
                if (m.matches()) {
                    // The platform endpoint already exists for this token, but with
                    // additional custom data that
                    // createEndpoint doesn't want to overwrite. Just use the
                    // existing platform endpoint.
                    m.group(1)
                } else {
                    // Rethrow the exception, the input is actually bad.
                    throw ipe
                }
            }
            storeEndpointArn(endpointArn!!)
          
            return endpointArn
        }

        /**
         * @return the ARN the app was registered under previously, or null if no
         * platform endpoint ARN is stored.
         */
        private fun retrieveEndpointArn(): String? {
            // Retrieve the platform endpoint ARN from permanent storage,
            // or return null if null is stored.
            return arnStorage
        }

        /**
         * Stores the platform endpoint ARN in permanent storage for lookup next time.
         */
        private fun storeEndpointArn(endpointArn: String) {
            // Write the platform endpoint ARN to permanent storage.
            arnStorage = endpointArn
        }
    }
}
```